How to update yt-dlp to nightly with Homebrew?
I used Homebrew to install yt-dlp. Now I need to update it to nightly.
When I use the command:
yt-dlp --update-to nightly

I get following message:

Unable to write to /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp; try running as administrator


I believe this would have to run in whatever local user context yt-dlp is installed, or, as the error states, it would need to run as an account that has permissions to write to the local user context. I guess if you focus your research on that, you may find a solution quickly.

If a specific build works, on a given day, why would you need to update it daily?

I can't download videos from Kick anymore, so I was suggested to update to nightly
